# How to run box shadow in Chrome and add a space between td tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

**1**. The box shadow works well in the IE and Firefox but it doesn't work in Chrome. Here is my CSS:

```
    body {
        background-color: #F6F6F6;
    }

    #showRoom {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table .box_shadow {
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 175px;
        height: 175px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
        box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    }

    table tr .text_plan {
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 175px;
        height: 175px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
    }

    .news {
        width: 309px;
        height: 175px;
        /*background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: relative;
    }

        .news:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .news_img {
        width: 309px;
        height: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.95;
    }

        .news_img div {
            width: 309px;
            height: 20px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            .news_img div p {
                font-size: 15px;
                color: #FFF;
            }

    span.imgswap {
        display: block;
    }
```

**2**. I would like to add a space between two `<td>` tags as an image below:

[image: A space between two <code><td></code> tags]

Here is the **JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/HQ6Eu/**

Comment: The image is broken..

Comment: I think that's OK as the **Unknown**'s comment below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add `display:block;` to your `table .box_shadow` css:

   ```
   table .box_shadow {
           background-color: #FFF;
           width: 175px;
           height: 175px;
           font-size: 18px;
           line-height: 20px;
           text-align: center;
           font-weight: normal;
           font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
            display:block;
            -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
           -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
           box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
   }
   ```
2. To add a space between two `<td>` tags use this:

   ```
   .news:nth-child(odd), .news_img:nth-child(odd){
        padding-right: 20px;
   }
   ```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/HQ6Eu/5/)**

Comment: Thank you. What if when there are more than 2 images?. I thought that the space between each image, should be flexible.

Comment: Thank you for your updated code. That works well with question 1 but it affects to my `<td>Plan 1</td>`. For the question 2, I need the space between each 2-image and there is no space for the last image..Please let me know that it is impossible to remove the space of the last image?

Comment: I have removed `width: 175px;` and `height: 175px;` in the class `table .box_shadow { }`. Thus, the `<td>Plan 1</td>` is now as itself.

Answer (score 1):

img classes should have a margin or padding to space them out.. see fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/HQ6Eu/3/

```
.news:nth-child(2), .news_img:nth-child(2)
{
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but this also adds the space between Plan 1 and the first image... I am now looking for a solution for adding a space between 2 images.